# ¿Cómo puedo interrelacionar tablas de diferentes bases de datos usando .net core?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando un proyecto y quisiera saber sí es posible relacionar tablas de diferentes bases de datos, por ejemplo:

Se tiene una base de datos de escuelas, cuya clase de Escuelas.cs sería la siguiente

```
public class Escuelas
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int EscuelaId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

De igual forma se tiene una base de datos de alumnos, los cuales pertenecen a una escuela en especifico, cuya clase de Alumnos.cs sería la siguiente:

```
public class Alumnos
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int AlumnoId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int EscuelaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EscuelaId")]
    public virtual Escuelas Escuela { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que me gustaría realizar es la interrelación entre la tabla Escuelas de la base de datos escuelas y la tabla de Alumnos de la base de datos alumnos, tengo entendido que se debe crear un contexto para cada base de datos, lo cual quedaría más o menos así:

En el starup.cs:

```
var connectionString1 = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection1' not found.");
var connectionString2 = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection2") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection2' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EscuelaContext>(dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions.UseMySql(connectionString1, serverVersion).LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().EnableDetailedErrors());

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AlumnoContext>(dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions.UseMySql(connectionString2, serverVersion).LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().EnableDetailedErrors());
```

En el appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "providerName": "MySql.Data.MySqlClient",
  "DefaultConnection1": "Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=escuelas;uid=root;password=",
  "DefaultConnection2": "Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=alumnos;uid=root;password=",
},
```

Y los contextos quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
 public class EscuelaContext : DbContext
 {
     public EscuelaContext(DbContextOptions<EscuelaContext> options) : base(options) { }

     public DbSet<Escuela> Escuelas { get; set; }
 }

public class AlumnoContext : DbContext
{
    public AlumnoContext(DbContextOptions<AlumnoContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Alumnos> Alumnos { get; set; }
}
```

Al momento de hacer la migración y la actualización de la base de datos me percato que la relación no se esta haciendo de manera correcta, ya que no se relaciona la base de datos de escuela con la de alumno, solo se crea la tabla de alumno y escuela en la misma base de datos y se hace la relación de forma automática, por lo cual quisiera saber si alguien ubica lo que me esta faltando o en su caso si en realidad es posible lo que estoy intentando hacer (Esto es solo un ejemplo).

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Para empezar, tu pregunta es sobre EF, no? segundo, no se quien diseño eso, pero que mala idea.. tercero, seguro, vas a necesitar que una base de datos tenga permisos para ver la otra, o si no, vas a tener que tratarlas como entidades totalmente separadas y leer las cosas de cada lado.

Comment: Estoy un 98.3124% seguro que eso no se puede hacer. ¿Cual es la idea de tener una base de datos de Escuelas y otra de Alumnos ?, porque podría entender una base de datos por cada escuela, pero cada una con sus respectivas tablas de Alumnos